# Symbolic link on Linux to a Windows-like file - not sure this is possible

Tags: linux, files, directory

I have to migrate a Windows application to Linux.  The directory/filename format within this Windows application are of the form `C:/dir/dir/file` (I know, not exactly Windows format with reference to the slashes but that is the format in the application, i.e. the directory/filename format is application-specific).

I don't think there is a way to do this.  The leading `C:` will be seen as a directory without a `/` and will fail to link on Linux.

Just wanted to know of there was a way around this.

Here is the command which (not surprisingly) fails:

```
ln -s /dir/dir/file C:/dir/dir/file
```

Thanks

Comment: "I have to migrate a Windows application to Linux" - then you have access to the source code. Fix it instead of trying to apply ugly hacks.

Comment: @symcbean I do not have access to the source.

Comment: "_I have to migrate a Windows application to Linux_" - seeing as you don't have the source, have you considered using `wine`?

Comment: @tale852150 if you don't have the source code, the grammar of file paths is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 2):

If you can be OK with this only working from a single directory, then you can simply `mkdir -p C:/dir/dir` and it should "just work".

If you want it to point elsewhere in the tree then you tell C: to be a symlink to the base directory.

e.g

```
ln -s / C:
```

So now `C:/dir/dir/file` will become `/dir/dir/file`

But this only works from the directory where you create the C: directory or symlink.

Comment: Yes, basically I just want C: to be /.  Nothing else needs to change.